# Searching CoreData relationships

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I'm about to pull my hair out trying to figure out why this isn't working.

I have two entities:

```
Quote

Customer
```

A `Quote` has a one-to-one relationship property with a `Customer` called simply '`customer`'. The Customer has a CoreData `objectID` (obviously). I am trying to search through all the Quote's and return the one's that have a specific Customer associated with it based off the `Customer` `objectID`. Reading through all the tutorials I've managed to get this but I keep getting a crash:

```
+ (void)fetchQuotesForCustomerID:(NSManagedObjectID*)objectID results:(void(^)(NSError* error, NSArray *fetchedResults))completion {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[QuoteGenerator sharedGenerator] managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Quote"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"customer.objectID == %@", objectID];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"fetch error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        completion(error, nil);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"fetch count = %d", fetchedObjects.count);
        completion(nil, fetchedObjects);
    }
}
```

Output error:

**`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath customer.objectID not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Quote id=13>'`**

Is the predicated setup wrong? Reading through the documentation is says that you can use dot syntax to access properties in the predicate.

Please help...

Comment: If one customer can have many quotes why aren't you using a one to many relationship and simply using core data to find the related quote objects?

Comment: @Gary thank you for your help. Lead me to the right answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do a fetch at all, core data should generate a quotes member on your customer object that will return an NSSet of all the related quote objects.

Comment: Your right! After a solid night of rest it's all coming together :) Thank you for your help

Comment: Without a fetch request, you lose the convenient fetchedResultsController, that gives you a great possibilities to handle updates and stuff. That is why I go for the solution bellow.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out a lack of sleep and @Gary lead me to the right answer.

1. I should have had a to-many relationship from customer to Quote.
2. When comparing an entities `NSManagedObjectID` property you don't have to explicitly state it. So the following modification to the `NSPredicate` fixed my issue.

> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY
>   customer == %@", objectID];